# How can I get into Arduino without the invitation email?`

Tags: support, area-51

I have committed to the Arduino proposal on Area 51. However, the invitation email must have gotten lost in my email account. Can I get in anyway?

Comment: Well, that's weird, there are **two**.  [One](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/58150/arduino) just entered beta a day ago, the [other](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/49538/arduino) was pronounced dead after 16 days in beta.  Don't pick the wrong one :)  And no, it won't, 0.1 answers is their lot as well.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212235/why-am-i-allowed-to-sign-up-on-a-private-beta-site-i-never-commited-to

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. Go [here](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/58150/arduino/visit) and log in. Confirm the creation of the account, and you should be good to go!