# Private Beta is accessible without an account

Tags: bug, area-51, beta-sites, private-beta

Go to a private beta site, such as [Spanish.SO](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/42810/stack-overflow-in-spanish/visit). You need an account on SE to get in.

Now, click on the StackExchange logo in the top left corner and press either "Stack Overflow en Español" or "Stack Overflow en Español Meta" or click on the Stack Overflow en Español logo above the heading "
Confirmar la nueva cuenta".

It directs you to the site homepage with questions, giving an outsider free access to the private beta.

I know about [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212235/why-am-i-allowed-to-sign-up-on-a-private-beta-site-i-never-commited-to) question, but this is letting someone even without a SE account go to the site.

Comment: AFAIK, the behavior is already like this for long time: you can browse private beta without joining, and even without an account. That's also the only way to create an account without committing the proposal (e.g. to flag spam). Whether it's a "workaround" or a bug, I'm not sure.

Comment: [status-bydesign] This has always been like this. You need an email invite, direct area 51 link or something like that to get in and create an account.